# Adding EKEvent invitees array directly using custom interface

Tags: ios, objective-c, calendar, ekeventkit, ekeventstore

I want to add invitees while scheduling meeting/event in such a way that EKEventEditViewController shows all the invitees pre-populated into it.But apple's documentation shows that invitees array is a read only property and we can not assign value to it.

I have seen it in some of the calendar apps where scheduling an event is done with custom interface and
with the custom fields(pre-populated invitees).I am confused that how can i achieve that?

Thanks In Advance.
VD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EKEvents can not be created using custom interface for iCal, however if we want to display custom schedule event interface, we can use MSGraph API to create exchange events.
Here is the SDK which can be useful in this case.
https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-ios